# Combo not updating using MVVM and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I having trouble DataBinding a combo in XAML using the MVVM method.

I set the combo's source in the code behind like so:

```
AgesViewModel agesViewModel = new AgesViewModel();
comboAge.SelectedValuePath = "AgeID";
comboAge.DisplayMemberPath = "Age";
comboAge.ItemsSource = agesViewModel.GetAges();
```

And the XAML for the combo is:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboAge"
          SelectedValue="{Binding AgeID}" />
```

The combo is part of a page with text controls and they all DataBind fine. The page DataContext is set to a ViewModel (carViewModel) which has a property called AgeID.

So when to combo items changed I want carViewModel.AgeID to be updated with the selected value.

Whenever I select an item from the combo nothing gets updated. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

I'm using XAML, C#4.5 and writing a windows store app in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow the MVVM pattern, have the ComboBox's data also available in your `carViewModel` and *bind* to it.

In other words:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboAge" ItemsSource="{Binding MyAgeList}" SelectedValue="{Binding AgeID}" />
```

When changing the value in the ComboBox, this will also update the `AgeID` property.

Assuming AgeID is int (it can, of course, be whatever you want) then `MyAgeList` should be defined like this in `carViewModel`:

```
public List<int> MyAgeList {get; set;}

// Constructor
public CarViewModel()
{
    MyAgeList = new AgesViewModel().GetAges();
}
```

Comment: OK, I've done that but I have the same results. The XAML for my come is now like this: <ComboBox x:Name="comboAge" ItemsSource="{Binding AgeList}" SelectedValue="{Binding AgeID}" SelectedValuePath="AgeID" DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>

Comment: And my CarViewModel is now like this: 
        public CarViewModel()
        {
            AgeList = new AgesViewModel().GetAges();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<AgeViewModel> AgeList { get; set; }

Comment: Why is AgeList a collection of ViewModels??

Comment: I'm trying to return a list of rows for my combo. Each row contains AgeID and a Description (which is my Age values (1-3, 4-6, etc). Surely I need to return this?

Comment: Then create a new class called AgeClass which has these 2 properties. This is your *model* (e.g. your *data* ). You should not create an array of *ViewModels* in this case. What does `GetAges()` return? It *should* return a List of this AgeClass...